# How to get the platform-specific text line terminator string in C++20?

Tags: c++, text, c++20

If there is a binary-mode `std::ostream`, how could one output a platform-specific line-terminator string (e.g. `\r\n` on Windows)? Alternatively, is there a standard way to get that terminator as a string?

So far, I have considered the following options:

- Just use `std::endl`: this would just output `\n` regardless of the platform, and the implied `std::flush` hurts performance quite severely.
- The old C-style `#ifdef _WIN32 ...` approach, with one branch per possible terminator string. Fragile and exhausting.
- A more modern branching alternative with `constexpr` conditionals. Slightly less fragile, still exhausting.
- Output `std::endl` to an `std::stringstream` and get the string: This does not seem to work when using `mingw` to compile a 64-bit Windows executable on Linux and testing using WINE - I still only get the single `\n`. That might be an environment problem, though.

Is there a somewhat portable way that would work?

**UPDATE:**

It was pointed out in the comments that having a line terminator is not a given; there are platforms that delimit text lines in other ways, like e.g. length-prefixed string records. So a truly generic solution would be one that answers the question:

> How to write a single platform-specific text line to a binary-mode output stream?

Is there, for example, a way to wrap a text-mode stream around an existing binary stream?

Comment: I think `std::endl` prints the same thing as `\n`, the conversion to `\r\n` is done by the stream opened in a text mode.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yes, `... << std::endl` is equivalent to `... << '\n' << std::flush`. But since my stream is in binary mode, I do not have anything to do the conversion to `\r\n` or whatever. I just included it as an option, to avoid bogus answers using `std::endl`.

Comment: Lines do not necessarily have terminators. A platform is allowed to implement a text file as e.g. a sequence of lines, where each line contains its own length embedded at the start. The C runtime will translate that to the usual '\n` terminator.

Comment: Why are you writing what I assume to be text to a stream opened in binary mode? The definition of a stream opened in text mode is that it performs that conversion for you, pretty much.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Hmmm.... true. I now find myself wondering with the C++ implementation does on platforms with OS-provided facilities for record-based I/O and such. Also, I wonder if there really is any platform where text does not use terminators by default...

Comment: @PaulSanders I've been playing with a silly binary archive format, and I've been trying to stash generated text files directly into the stream, without an intermediate file. I don't _really_ need anything but `\n` right now, but the pedant in me still wants to get this part right. Also, curiosity is a factor :-)

Comment: I vaguely recall that on some mainframes (IBM/360?) this was the case. Lines were records, with length maintained by the disk/tape hardware. I could be out of my mind though.

Comment: Hmm, looks like OpenVMS may indeed be storing text files in a record stream. Interesting.

Comment: @n. Probably not.  Back in the day (and this is showing my age) I worked on a Texas 990 minicomputer, and that stored lines in text files with a character count at the beginning and end of each line?  Why?  So you could process the file backwards if you wanted to, clearly (??) a much-needed feature.  It came back to bite us though.  If a program crashed while writing such a file and didn't get around to writing out a complete line, then the system would crash (I'm not lying!) when it next tried to read the file.  That made us popular with our users, I can tell you.

Comment: @PaulSanders The ability to process a file on a spool of tape backwards is a real godsend.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Since you've got a binary file, why don't you just print the exact sequence you want? `constexpr auto& linend="\r\n"; outfile.write(linend,2);`

Comment: @Red.Wave: Because I don't want an _exact_ sequence; I want the one mandated by the target platform, and I'm trying to avoid an annoying if-then-else mess that would require me to map terminators to platforms (some of which I'd have trouble to test on).

Comment: @thkala then do something even nastyer: create a random text file, write a line, close, read back as binary, save ending along with its size, delete the file. This only works in simple case with delimiters. I'd go for a `consteval` function with preprocessor `#if`s.

Comment: _I've been playing with a silly binary archive format, and I've been trying to stash generated text files directly into the stream, without an intermediate file._ OK, why not open those files in binary mode?  A-ha!

Comment: n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ah yes, silly me. (Which is a whole heap better than my previous comment, now deleted, sorry about that).

Comment: @PaulSanders: *OK, why not open those files in binary mode?* Sorry, should have been more clear. I'm generating the files, and stashing them into the archive within the same process. I was trying to skip the temporary file write-out/read-in cycle. For now I have worked around the problem by hard-coding known terminators for the 2-3 platforms I really care about, but it'd have been nice to find a somewhat reasonable standard solution. I suspect that's not possible, though. Looking more deeply into e.g. OpenVMS, it sounds like text and binary files can be fundamentally different at an OS level.

Comment: Are your archives intended to be readable on a platform other than the one you generated them on?  Sounds like there might be a whole other can of worms there, not just how text is represented.

Comment: @PaulSanders: No, they are read on the same platform. Anyway, at this point I'm fairly sure that what I'm asking for is intentionally not possible in C++, because of the need to support platforms where "text" is an OS-level property.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that something like this may not actually be possible, intentionally. C++ needs to support a multitude of platforms, and some of them have fundamentally different models for text files.

E.g. on OpenVMS text files can be stored in a record-per-line format using the [Record Management Services](https://wiki.vmssoftware.com/RMS) subsystem. This makes the concept of line terminator strings irrelevant, and it also means that text-mode files are not just binary files with some additional assumptions on top of them.